# How to use driver.find_element() to locate an element and click on it using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to ask aobut `driver.find_element()`. I want to make the automatic site login with a chrome driver and python. I want to click the login button, but it doesn't work.

Here is code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys       
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()     
driver.get('https://www.naver.com')
time.sleep(2)

search = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'link_login')  
search.click()
```

I also used

```
search = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'link_login')
```

but it didn't work too. How can I make it to work?

Answer (score 0):

You were close. To click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CLASS_NAME*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "link_login"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.link_login"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='link_login']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```